# Why were two users were removed within the past hour?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

Were *two* users removed within the past hour?

Why do they do this?  Are they somehow offended by something happening here?  If so what sorts of complaints are typical?

Comment: I wonder such things, as well as what obligation the mods (admins?) have to honor requests for deletion.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the removal of the user was not done by any of our mods (our mod tools show nothing at all on this). This probably means that it was done by someone at SE, so we have no info at all. It appears to have been a high-rep user (about 6500), if my guess based in Googling is correct. Had I known in advance, I would have tried to convince the user to stay, and tried to learn about any problems sparking the decision to leave, so that we might attempt to address them.

Comment: I also want to know why I see $-10$ and $-40$ reputation deductions (total $50$) on the two removed users; but my reputation went from $53,395$ to $53,335$ (actual deduction $60$). This is a $10$ points difference. The last time I checked $10\neq 0$. Did SE prove PA inconsistent when I was busy writing my thesis??

Comment: Is there no way to find what the user name was?

Comment: I lost -25, -25 and I don't have that many to lose.The departure of a good voter is a loss in itself, but perhaps the system can be adjusted to mitigate the point-impact of these tempests? Would it hurt? I think requests to leave should be honored. But need that undo everything that was done prior?

Comment: @daniel: that particular angle has been discussed here on meta before. I'd look it up, but this mobile has only a small, cracked screen :)

Comment: @TheChaz: Thanks, I'll check. Thought I'd post a comment while I still have enough points :).

Comment: @daniel I've written [a feature request on Meta.SO that votes of deleted users should remain and should not be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) a while ago. It is highly upvoted, but hasn't been implemented so far.

Comment: @MadScientist: Good. I think it makes sense. Typically the people who leave turbulence in their wake were higher-ranked members. It militates in favor of retaining their opinions about things post-departure. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious: when a user asks to be removed, are his/her questions and/or answers to questions also removed/undone/deleted?

Comment: @amWhy No, it looks like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/180861/21674).

Answer (score 18):

This really isn't an answer to the present question, but I don't want to clutter up the comments, and it *does* speak to the "fall out" that occurs when a user asks to be removed.
And given the lack of communication from the two users who asked to be removed, I am going to speak up and speculate a bit: I refrained from participating at Math.se for nearly a year - in part - because of issues I will address shortly. I did not choose to remove myself when I decided to "walk away".

But the absence of most users @ math.se goes easily unnoticed. I'm sure my lack of participation went unnoticed. In contrast, given the question at hand and the ensuing comments, the absence of the users who chose to remove themselves from math.se, or at least one of those users, *did **not** go unnoticed*.

Thought: perhaps a user, "high-rep" or not, may be trying to make a "statement", so to speak, with respect to his/her departure, which may not be noticed otherwise than by asking to be removed. Likewise, as I am currently feeling rather ambivalent about math.se and my perception of the dynamics that play out here, if I ask to be removed, it will likely be noticed because I have cast *a lot* of upvotes!

*There are less than desirable dynamics occurring here at math.se that have nothing to do with the quality, or lack thereof, of questions and answers.*

First, I suspect - without pointing fingers - that there is a "likability" factor which contributes to voting patterns which doesn't say anything about the quality of an answer, question, or comment: voting patterns that reflect personal biases having nothing to do with the quality of a particular question and/or the veracity and helpfulness of a given answer. Despite the fact that math.se is purportedly for math Q&A, voting patterns (at least as I see it) reflect much more than mathematical veracity and/or helpfulness.

For example, I've seen - on more than a few occasions - some of the most high-rep users post an *incorrect* answer and yet receive a handful upvotes within one minute of posting, even when others have already posted correct answers and yet, remain deprived of upvotes.
In other words, if we let $Rx$ represent "$x$ has high rep", $Ux$ correlate with "$x$ gets an upvote", and $Lx$ express "$x$ is likable or well-liked",

then I am suggesting that it is *not necessarily* the case that we can then assume:

$$\exists x(Ux \rightarrow Rx).$$

I suspect that the converse also plays out here:

$$\exists x(Rx \rightarrow Ux)$$

and additionally,

$$\exists x(Lx \rightarrow Ux)$$

(*Note*: I have taken the liberty of using $\rightarrow$ in a *semi-causal* sense..., which cannot be captured by "strict" implication.)

Also, it seem there are many occasions in which a sophisticated answer assumes far more advanced mathematical maturity if it is to be of help, which receives a handful of upvotes because the answer correlates with the *upvoters'* level of understanding, but which are plainly *way over-the-head* of the OP (i.e., answers which assume knowledge which is far beyond the scope of the OP's level of education, and hence, may be horribly confusing and thus unhelpful to the OP). Granted, for future users, those answers may be helpful, so I'm not implying sophisticated answers do not belong; rather, I'm observing that votes often seem to correspond to "who outwits others" vs. who is most helpful. (I am reluctant provide links to such questions/answers because I do not want to "finger-point" anyone!)

Granted, there is meta-math.se to make such a statement (of "washing ones hands of the site"), but then a "disgruntled" user has to deal with the possibility of a barrage of "downvotes", which would only further discourage him/her.

> $(*)$ Assuming that a disgruntled user does not want to "go public" to discuss an issue, ideally we would like him/her to contact and/or flag a moderator to discuss it before officially asking to be removed altogether.

Otherwise, if s/he is determined to be removed, perhaps there should be two other options, so it's not an all-or-nothing matter:

$(1)$ the option of negating the impact of his/her participation here, in terms of previous votes, and

$(2)$ the option of being removed while leaving their votes stand. Could this be a feature request? Some who want to be removed may very well *not* want to deprive others of the rep corresponding to his/her upvotes.

To end (yes, I'm going to wrap this up!)

I suspect there are many users whose participation consists mostly of voting, editing, and/or commenting - all of which are welcome and valuable. If we value such contribution, so long as such users have the option of being removed, along with their votes, the math.se community is held accountable, to some small degree, to keeping this site a welcoming arena in which to participate.

Comment: I would like to add another formula.
$$\exists x(\neg Lx \rightarrow \neg Ux)$$
i.e. disliking tends to cause downvotes.

Comment: I am truly confused by the existential quantifiers.

Comment: I actually noticed that you went missing, and I was glad to see that you were back.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker No intention to confuse.  I was trying not to make a global statement - so qualified by the existential quantifier. Indeed, the expressions are over-simplified!

Comment: @amWhy Why should one ever have the right to take away all their votes? I am not allowed to change my previous votes after some time, so why should I be able to do this in the least discriminating manner?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: actually, at present, you do have the right to change your votes/delete up/down votes by asking to be removed. At any rate, I'm not necessarily implying it's a right; but I think that as things stand, perhaps we should focus more on making the site as hospitable as possible, and less on the loss of a little rep.

Comment: FWIW I did notice that you were absent for a longish while. I think that more often than not somebody will notice, when a regular conributor fades out. Even if only temporarily. There are several easily imaginable reasons (related to work or personal matters) for that to happen. Therefore people are reluctant to draw attention to it. Arturo being a notable exception.

Comment: Concerning the observations: (1) I have definitely received the occasional unwarranted immediate upvote or two for an answer that needed serious repairs. (2) I see quite a few correct answers that I think are clearly too sophisticated for the OP, and I’ve the impression that it’s not unusual for them to receive more upvotes than the accepted answer. This isn’t altogether bad: those answers may be very useful to someone who comes across them in the future. But I do sometimes wince a bit at the apparent lack of concern for the actual OP.

Comment: @Brian I appreciate your comment, and your taking the time to comment. I just wish there were some place to "vent" on this site. I sort of tried to do that here, in this question. But, alas, *not one moderator* has replied or commented. Have you considered being a moderator, should the opportunity arise?

Comment: Just long enough to shudder at the thought! I’ve been in analogous positions elsewhere, and I know that it would take an awful lot of the fun out of things. I don’t rule it out categorically, but I think it pretty unlikely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I suspect moderating is a bit of a thankless place to be. Take my comment as a vote of confidence, at any rate.

Comment: And I thank you for it.

Comment: @MakotoKato I agree completely - I thought I responded to your comment earlier; I know I upvoted the comment. Anyway, I agree whole-heartedly. I should have elaborated a bit more on the phenomena of being "liked" vs. being "unliked" and the impact that has on voting. It seems one can easily risk being dismissed, ignored, etc. for reasons that have nothing to do with the quality of one's participation on this site. Thanks, for chiming in.

Answer (score 15):

We're obligated to remove user accounts and personally-identifying information upon request. While we do try to avoid this (if the person is willing to share his reasoning with us, we'll try to mediate disputes or correct problems), often it is too late by the time we're contacted.

And yes, two accounts were removed upon their owners' request yesterday.

---

In response to the comments: we *don't* hold accounts hostage; we're bound by our [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), the [CC BY-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) under which all content is contributed, [our published deletion policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account), and basic human decency to honor such requests - provided they're made in compliance with such policies - in a reasonable amount of time.

We do try - particularly in the case of older, high-reputation accounts - to work with the folks requesting deletion, to see if a less destructive resolution can be found. However, they're under no obligation to work with us or provide us with any information beyond "this is my account and I want it gone".

My advice to moderators wishing to avoid this is to *not let it get that far.* If you're letting a situation degrade to the point where someone feels they're unwelcome here, you've already missed your best chance to mitigate the problem - so don't sit around waiting to hear from *us*, **get in touch with the person and try to fix it**. Leaving an annotation on the profile is a good idea as well - we do try to investigate these before taking any action, but if there's nothing visible this fails; whether or not we'll take the time to involve moderators at this point depends considerably on what information we're able to garner from the account itself or its owner.

Comment: Why were we (MSE mods) not consulted (as promised) before the removal of one of our high-rep users? Being more familiar with the site, we may have been able to have resolved the matter much  more *constructively* (as we *have* done many times in the past).

Comment: The deletion of person-identifying information doesn't really work for many hig rep users. As long as someone adressed them in comments under the original name and they posted in the same place,  one can figure out a users number and use google to search for that users activity.

Comment: The high-rep user in question requested that ALL of their accounts be deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 If memory serves correct, the high-rep user had high-rep only on our site (over 6500 here), with rep an order of magnitude lower on all other SE sites. So the user removal hurts us much more than other SE sites. Even if we were not able to convince the user to stay, by speaking to the user, we might have learned things that would help us to address problems on the site. That is why we prefer that you let us have a hand in these matters. Generally, we have more site-specific knowledge, hence more of a chance of achieving better resolutions.

Comment: @BillDubuque How would one (a user) contact a moderator (not necessarily "any" moderator (any in the sense of random, e.g. by flagging) to address issues, short of posting on meta...I'd be happy to add that option in my "answer"...some who are unhappy here, may not feel comfortable "airing" their issues on the site...

Comment: @BillDubuque The prerequisite for this is that the user is willing to talk to the Math.SE mods. My personal experience is that the SE team will contact the mods of the affected sites if there is still some chance to prevent deletion. If the user is determined to delete the account there's nothing they can do to stop it.

Comment: @amWhy: You can always find the email of *some* moderators on their user account. Or you could flag and request an email to be sent to you...

Comment: @MadScientist But the SE team is rarely (if ever) in the best position to judge whether their is "some chance to prevent deletion". Generally this requires very specific site knowledge, which requires regular participation on MSE.

Comment: @BillDubuque But they have to make this judgement, as they are the ones contacted in many cases. And I don't think we should start to require deletion to go through the specific site mods. I disagree with the side-effects user deletion has, but the decision to delete belongs to the user in question alone, and no one else. If they aren't willing to talk about it, there's nothing else to do except following their request.

Comment: @MadScientist I think it would be better if the "contact us" links recommended that users email site mods (vs. SE team) regarding account deletions, and providing a mailing list for contacting site mods. The site mods often know the reasons why a user is upset and, as such, have a better chance of engaging the user in constructive conversation (especially for "rage quitting").

Comment: @BillDubuque I know of cases where the SE team has asked the site mods about self-deletion requests they received. So this is already happening to some extent.

Comment: @MadScientist I can only speak for the time that I have been a moderator, during which I don't recall the SE team consulting the MSE mods on any user removals, even though the community coordinator has said this should occur for users with nontrivial rep. I was quite surprised (and disappointed) to learn that a 6500 rep user was recently removed without our consultation.

Comment: @Bill: see my edit. I've worked with moderators regarding user deletions on numerous occasions, but in the vast majority of cases this simply isn't feasible because the person involved has no interest in further communication. You're far better off stepping in sooner rather than later; by the time it gets to us, they've already jumped through a few hoops.

Comment: @Shog9: You said that you investigate when annotations are left in the user profile. Do you mean when someone changes the comment to "Please delete this account" or is there some other thing? And how do you get notified when such annotation is made?

Comment: @Shog9 Your edit does not address the points that I raised. How can the *SE team* possibly provide the *most optimal* way to resolve such matters when, generally, they have no knowledge of the site-specific issues? It is *essential* that site mods are involved in this process if there is to be any hope to resolve these matters optimally. Why were we not contacted in this case despite prior remarks that this would occur? Is there no official SE policy on such matters? If not, how do I formally request that some policy be implemented?

Comment: @Bill: we can't. The most optimal way involves the moderators who are on the site, in direct communication with the folks involved *every day*, and deals with the problem before it reaches us. When that fails, we do the best we can. You might be interested in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151874/delay-user-requests-for-account-deletion-by-24-hours), btw - but keep in mind, there **cannot** be a change in policy that would *prevent* users from deleting their accounts.

Comment: @Asaf: the bio text change is required purely as a proof of ownership (yes, we do occasionally get deletion requests from folks who... don't own the accounts they want deleted). Moderators have access to a private annotation function that lets them leave short notes on user accounts, visible only to other moderators (and SE staff) - if someone's working with an account, an annotation helps to ensure someone else doesn't step on their toes.

Comment: @Shog9: Oh. Quite clever. Now I'm curious about this feature. I should become a moderator or on the SE team just to see if my account has any annotation. Are you guys hiring? :-)

Comment: @Shog9 *Still* you do not answer my question. Why can't you involve the site specific moderators? I don't know where you got the strange idea that I requested a "change in policy that would prevent users from deleting their accounts". Did you read what I wrote above?

Comment: @Bill: and you're not reading what I wrote. We handle each request individually, and for high-rep users we'll always *at minimum* offer to help work through any problems they might have on the site. If we can, by looking at the account, figure out what those problems might be, we'll go further. But unless we know what the problem entails, we can't pass the buck. Believe it or not, sometimes the problem *is* the moderators - passing such a request off would be counter-productive.

Comment: @Asaf: http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring (and just to rub it in... There is *one* annotation...) (no, you shouldn't worry about it)

Comment: @Shog9 I strongly disagree that - in general - the *SE team* can have any hope of "knowing what the problem entails" better than the site-specific mods. It is sad that you refuse to give us the information that we need to better resolve these problems.

Comment: @Bill: you're arguing both sides of this. Either you have more information than us *and should already be working on resolving the issue*, leaving notes on the account and such - or you don't, and can't really contribute anything to the process. We get enough requests that we recently hired another person *purely* to help us handle them in a timely manner - adding more overhead to the process in cases where there's absolutely no indication that it will do any good isn't going to happen; asking us to spend more time on folks you haven't bothered to work with isn't going to go over well either.

Comment: @Shog9 Huh? Simply because we have more site-specific information than you does not imply that we are *omnipresent*. We mods cannot be everywhere to handle every spark before it becomes a flame. But when they do, often we have enough knowledge of site dynamics, politics, etc that we can find  constructive resolutions that don't involve user deletion (which we have done in the past for users who contacted us instead of the SE team). Why not require them to contact the site mods, and let us forward to you when need be?

Comment: The part of this I don't understand is why account deletion entails vote reversal.  The user's identifying information is gone, fine. But why should their votes be reversed? If every trace of the user was being expunged, deleting their votes would at least be consistent. But that isn't what is happening, since their questions and answers remain. What is the rationale for deleting the votes?

Comment: @MJD: I imagine it started as an implementation detail - obviously it's worth putting extra effort into designing a system that can continue hosting posts after their author has left, but the value of retaining votes is somewhat less obvious. As a side-effect of this, it allows the deletion of sockpuppet accounts to automatically nullify any ill-gotten reputation, though of course that could be achieved in other ways. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted

Comment: @Shog9 The whole vote fraud topic really needs dedicated tools anyway, if only to educate mods about the correct way to deal with this. The current way is rather confusing, and sometimes rather dangerous (especially when merging users).

Comment: @Shog9 I'm glad to know that when one one asks to have one's account deleted, one's questions and answers remain.

Comment: @amWhy: I think that not all posts are preserved. Posts with negative score may be deleted under some circumstances.

Comment: @Asaf ...I don't have any posts with negative score...so no worries there.

Answer (score 1):

**Extended Comment**

I actually do not see any reason why any serious user should ever be removed.

The effect of deleting a user seems to be that that users account profile cannot be visited anymore, the username changes to *userXXXX* with the Xs representing digits, the votes get cancelled, and the user cannot use the account anymore. If we, as a community, decide that the cancelling of votes is undesirable (except for sockpuppets, spammers etc.), one can just change the name of a user, delete all profile information and the moderators suspend the user indefinitely.

Do moderators have to respect removal requests?

Comment: Moderators don't have the ability to remove *all* the profile information. So if you want to remove all personal information you have to delete the user. It is SE policy to accept requests for account removal. The correct way to change this is in my opinion to change the mechanics of user deletion, and to allow for the votes to remain even if the user is deleted.

Comment: @MadScientist I agree of course that this is not a very elegant solution, but it is better than what we have now. The profile part should be a minor issues. Users who want their account to be killed can be expected to clean up their profile themselves.

Comment: There's more stuff that contains private information, the IP addresses that the account was accessed from, the connected OpenID providers, and old mail adresses can still be visible from the account history in some cases. My point is that if privacy concerns are the reason for the request to delete the account, nothing short of actual deletion will satisfy this.